# OAuth 2.0 from Google Apps Script (GAS) to Sheets API

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

Based on the [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values?hl=en#appending_values), I've implemented the following code to append a row to the Google Sheet (and I'm owner of this sheet).

```
function addSalaryLog(updateArray) {
  const resource = {
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [updateArray]
  };
  const spreadsheetId = 'here_goes_the_spreadsheet_id';
  const range = 'A:A';
  const optionalArgs = {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(resource, spreadsheetId, range, optionalArgs);
}
```

When I call it, in return I get the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to
> sheets.spreadsheets.values.append failed with error: Request is
> missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access
> token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

No need to ask, I clicked the link :-) It explains how to create an OAuth 2.0 in the developer console. Created ✅. But later it does not explain how to actually authorize the script.
I expect that before calling the Sheets API, I should be able to trigger launching the permission dialog.

I see the following, possible options:

1. Instead of `Sheets....` use `URLFetch`.
2. Trigger the authentication (preferred).
   Any tips here?

**UPDATE**
I've implemented `testAddSalaryLog()` which is exactly the same as the original function but has hardcoded values. And it works! It makes me think that the solution is to force the permission screen to trigger.

Comment: Permission screen should trigger automatically. Do you have some sort of popup blocker?

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 questions/suggestions:

**Question 1.**

Since you are using the Sheets API. Have you enabled the [Google Sheets API advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) in your script? From `Editor` > `Service` > `Google Sheet API`?

[image]

[image]

**Question 2.**

Have you reviewed if the "Sheets API scope" were added to the script by reviewing the project `Overview`? If they were not added automatically, you need to [add them manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) by following these steps:

1. Access the 'Project Settings' to enable the manifest file in the editor.
   [image]
2. Return to the editor and select 'appsscript.json'
   [image]
3. Add the scopes:

   `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",`
   `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",`
   `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"`
   [image]

**Question 3.**

Have you [authorized](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script#step_3_run_the_sample) the code already?

In the Apps Script editor, click `Run`. The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:

Select `Review permissions` > `Allow.`

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append scopes](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#authorization-scopes)
- [Google Apps Script Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script)
- [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)
- [Setting explicit scopes for Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)

Comment: Hey, very valid questions, and all already checked. In specific:

1. Checked this + additional services. Also added OAuth as library
2. Scopes defined. Initially I used `spreadsheets` only, but after your suggestion added the remaining two.
3. Manual "Run" in the code editor triggers the authorize request, but run from the Spreadsheet doesn't ask for authorization.

Comment: Also, I did a simple check. Please see the "update" section in the initial question.